# Better to use static Enumerable FirstOrDefault over the object's method?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq

While I was working on some code Resharper had a 'suggestion' to use the static Enumberable.FirstOrDefault() :

Originally the code was similar to this:

```
var myCountry = myCountryRepository.GetByCode(code); // returns IEnumerable of Country
Country country = myCountry.FirstOrDefault();
```

The suggestion changed the last line to this:

```
Country country = Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(myCountry);
```

Is there a performance gain by using the static method?

Comment: No, it compiles to the same thing. Resharper is just giving you the option. It will now be "suggesting" you change it back. Much like it will tell you that `var` can be changed to an explicit type and vice versa.

Comment: What version of ReSharper does that? I cannot find the check in the settings of my 8.2 installation.

Comment: @AntP You should post that as an answer since it does a better job of explaining the whole concern than the existing answer.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Every version afaik - if you hover over `var` and press Alt+Enter (by default) it gives you "quick fixes" - they're not necessarily suggestions, just shortcuts to equivalent conversions.

Comment: @AntP Ah, I see what you mean. I thought OP is talking about a suggestion with a squiggly line in the code, not about an option for quick refactoring.

Comment: If that's the case then I've no idea how he's managed that.

Comment: I'm using Resharper 7.1.3. Yes, the 'hammer' suggestion does go back and forth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no performance gain: the two calls are absolutely identical. When you write

```
Country country = myCountry.FirstOrDefault();
```

the compiler recognizes that you are calling an extension method, and quietly converts it to this:

```
Country country = Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(myCountry);
```

Comment: myCountry.FirstOrDefault() - FirstOrDefault is an extension method of the System.Linq namespace. Look at the syntax for creating extension methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx